# Migrate VM's residing on standalone ESX host to Azure

Tags: azure, vmware

I have deployed Azure Migrate appliance but it seems it can only connect to vCenter server and not a standalone ESXi host. The same seems to be the case with Azure Vmware Solutions by Cloud Simple.
Are there any other simple ways of migrating workloads to Azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure at this time only supports Azure Migrate through a VCSA and not a standalone ESXi host.

Answer (score 2):

Treat it like a physical server and migrate.  I have done thousands of VMs this way for a large customer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-migrate-physical-virtual-machines